# Cordova app: PDF is displayed to the user without having them choosing a browser for it

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, inappbrowser

I am working on mobile application using IONIC - Cordova framework. I want to open a PDF file on an Android native browser with this code

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal: true });
```

But when I click on the PDF icon connected with the above code it first shows dialog box for selecting the browser ("Chrome", "Internet", "Adobe Reader".. etc.).

[image]

**I don't want to browser selection steps in between.**

I am using a Samsung device. Let me know if it is a particular device issue.

Comment: Included the picture and re-worded the text for better readability

Comment: Thanks for including the picture.

Comment: This seems to be working as expected. The user should decide how to open PDF files on their phone.